# How to get class Constructor parameteres using Apache BCEL?

Tags: java, bcel

I 'm able to get methods using BCEL but is it possible to get constructors of a class using the same library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; the constructors are considered methods by BCEL.  They are named `<init>` instead of the class's name.